# How to set size of UIImageView equal to size of UIImage?

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uiimage

I have an view controller with `UIImageView` named `someImageView`. This image view has no default `UIImage`. I'm loading `UIImage` with the code below:

```
UIImage * myImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"sampleImage.png"];
someImageView.image = myImage;
```

The size of `sampleImage.png` is 320x300. I need to set size of `someImageView` to size exactly equal to `sampleImage.png`. I'm trying to do it:

```
CGRect frame = someImageView.frame;
frame.size = myImage.size;
someImageView.frame = frame;
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: Any reason for not using the `initWithImage:` method of `UIImageView`? That does exactly what you need.

Comment: Enable autolayout width/height of the image view and then use content modes according to your need - I believe enabling - clip subviews and setting the content mode will do the trick for you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to change `contentMode` to `UIViewContentModeScaleToFill` of your imageView

```
someImageView.image = myImage;
someImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;

CGRect frame = someImageView.frame;
frame.size = myImage.size;
someImageView.frame = frame;
```